# How to use OpenIE options?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am not able to use options of openie,
I am using this command

```
 java -mx3g -resolve_coref -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE
```

and the error I am getting is

```
Unrecognized option: -resolve_coref
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Moreover I tried changing the default value in code, like this -

```
  @ArgumentParser.Option(name="resolve_coref", gloss="If true, resolve pronouns to their canonical mention")
  private boolean resolveCoref = true;
```

with this I don't get an error message.
 But the output does not change,
For eg. Arya is a good girl and she likes apple.

```
The tuples extracted are -
1.0 arya is good girl
1.0 she likes apple
1.0 arya is good
1.0 arya is girl
```

What I want is she replaced by arya in the tuple.
Is there any other method using which I can do it?